How to use zebra scan on flutter?
I'm using this code to listen what my Zebra TC25 read.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class ScanReader extends HookWidget {
  const ScanReader({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    useEffect(() {
      thisHandle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        print(keyEvent);
        return true;
      }

      HardwareKeyboard.instance.addHandler(thisHandle);
      return () {
        HardwareKeyboard.instance.removeHandler(thisHandle);
      };
    }, []);

    return const Text("Zebra scan listener");
  }
}

The problem is my function thisHandle is never trigger. Why ?

To listen for KeyEvent send by Datawedge in Zebra you need to Send characters as events, as described here: https://developer.zebra.com/blog/listening-keypress-events-datawedge

It is also recommended to send TAB and ENTER events as described here: https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/DataWedge-for-Android-Send-Enter-or-Tab-after-scanning?language=en_US


This way your function thisHandle should be triggered.
